# Python Unittest value returned from intermediate method

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, mocking

I have a Flask app that exposes a method that expects a post value.  In this endpoint, I take the request data and create an event that I send to Kafka. Depending on what the request value contains, the event is different.  I want to write a series of tests that validates that the method that creates my event works as expected.  Without a whole ton of details, this is the basic structure of the Gateway resource.

```
class Gateway(Resource):
    def build_event(self, request):
        event = {
            "key": uuid4(),
            "source_ip": request.remote_addr,
            "payload_checksum": = haslib.md5(request.data).hexdigest(),
            ...
        }
        if request.data['some-key']:
             event["key-specific-value"] = "foo"
        else:
             event["key-specific-value"] = "bar"


    def post(self):
        event = self.build_event(request)
        kafka_producer.send(event)
```

I want to write some tests that allow me to call the post method, and verify that the event that is returned from build_event is correct.
How can inspect the value of the structure returned from build_event in a unit test?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to test multiple methods in a test case. Write one test for `post` that mocks `self.build_event` and `kafka_producer.send`. Then, write another test case that only calls `build_event` and check the return value of that.

To answer your original question, you can create a mock object and pass that in as your request parameter like this:

```
def test_build_event(self):
    mock_request = mock.Mock(remote_addr='some remote address', data={'some-key': False})
    gateway = Gateway()
    event_return_val = gateway.build_event(mock_request)
    self.assertEqual(event_return_val['key-specific-value'], 'bar')
    self.assertTrue('key' in event_return_val)
```

You can get more complex and `mock.patch` the calls to `uuid4()` and `hashlib.md5()` as well. That will allow you to compare to an exact value in your returned `event` and the patched return values. To start out with though, you can just check to see if the keys exist like I did in the case above.